# ¿Cómo solucionar este Error en comando de docker : invalid reference format?

Tags: windows, docker, nginx

estoy tratando de ejecutar este comando desde vs code en docker, solo para copiar mi proyecto en un conedor con nginx

```
 docker run -d -p 3001:80 --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

pero siempre devuelve el error de `docker: invalid reference format`.

No se que es lo que puede estar mal, lo unico diferente es que vi este comando ejecutarse en linux  y yo estoy usando windows pero el comando pwd igualmente funciona en windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Válido el intento, pero no puedes usar todo así nada más entre linux y windows. Algún día (cuando Microsoft quiera)

Por ahora, debes revisar el comando que estás intentando ejecutar. Seguro lo estás ejecutando desde la carpeta en la que tienes tu proyecto, `C:\Workspace\proyecto`. El problema está en que `pwd` sólo funciona en los shell de Unix (como bash) y en PowerShell (al menos en la versión más reciente que tengo acá en Windows 10). ¿Entiendes lo que pasa ahora?

Esto es lo que dice PS:

```
PS C:\Users\user> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\user
```

Esto es lo que pasa si corro la terminal ahí dentro y lo intento:

```
PS C:\Users\user> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>pwd
'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Al decirle `-v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html`, le intentas decir que agarre la carpeta actual y la comparta con el contenedor y se la monte en esa ruta `/usr/share/nginx/html` DENTRO DEL CONTENEDOR para que ese nginx sirva tu proyecto como si nada (mira la [documentación](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) de Docker siempre. En general, mira siempre la documentación, que es hecha por otros que sufrieron antes que tú y quieren ahorrarle sufrimiento al mundo). Pero pues, Windows.

Así pues, tendrás que correr tus comandos docker desde PowerShell para que `pwd` signifique algo.

Lo otro, si desde PS sigue sin funcionar así no más, puedes intentar adaptarla ligeramente para que entienda que debe usar PWD (y lo sigues haciendo en PowerShell, claro):

```
docker run -d -p 3001:80 --name website -v ${PWD}:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

No se que shell se esta usando pero probablemente  `$(pwd)` no este evaluando como esperas. Intenta usando `${pwd}` que funcionaría en algunos Powershell.

Tambien podrias verificar si la ruta que se evalue en `$(pwd)` tiene espacios. En este caso debes encerrar la expresion entre comillas `"$(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html"`